# How to open last document saved automatically?

Tags: cocoa

When my application launches I would like to automatically open the last document saved without user intervention.

My plan is to save the location of file last saved into user-defaults possibly in dataOfType.

I will also prevent to open untitled document by returning NO in `applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile` in my app-controller.

So in theory this should be possible but how? How do I open a document programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this answer from Cocoa with Love.

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    // On startup, when asked to open an untitled file, open the last opened
    // file instead
    if (!applicationHasStarted)
    {
        // Get the recent documents
        NSDocumentController *controller =
            [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];
        NSArray *documents = [controller recentDocumentURLs];

        // If there is a recent document, try to open it.
        if ([documents count] > 0)
        {
            NSError *error = nil;
            // point to last document saved
            NSInteger index = 0;
            [controller
                openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:[documents objectAtIndex:index]
                display:YES error:&error];

            // If there was no error, then prevent untitled from appearing.
            if (error == nil)
            {
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Original link: [Open the previous document on application startup](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/open-previous-document-on-application.html)

Comment: Above solution fixed my problem.

Comment: I believe your code is now wrong - the CocoaWithLove code runs as expected: it opens the last opened/saved document, whereas your code opens the oldest one. Maybe it was a bug in the version of OS X you're using?

Comment: You are right Adam. It is wrong. I think I must have been mislead by my observations at the time, I can't remember the details today unfortunately. The latest version of the code has index set to zero and it works as you said, but I don't remember when I changed the code and why. This issue should be closed/erased not to mislead others. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I'ved edited your answer to use the 0 index instead (I'd already edited it to correct a typo) if someone else will peer review it, it will be fine.

Comment: When should the *applicationHasStarted* flag be set to true? In *applicationDidFinishLaunching* ?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 example: (code goes in your Application Delegate)

```
func applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {

    let documentController = NSDocumentController.shared

    if let mostRecentDocument = documentController.recentDocumentURLs.first {
        documentController.openDocument(withContentsOf: mostRecentDocument, display: true, completionHandler: { (document, documentWasAlreadyOpen, errorWhileOpening) in
            // Handle opened document or error here
        })
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```